# How to use tf.unique_with_counts for each row/column of a tensor

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, artificial-intelligence, nearest-neighbor

I'm trying to solve KNN using tensorflow. After I get the K neighbours for N vectors, I have a N by K tensor. Now, for each vector in N, I need to use [`tf.unique_with_counts`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique_with_counts) to find the majority vote. However, I cannot iterate in a tensor and I cannot run [`tf.unique_with_counts`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/unique_with_counts) with a multi-dimensional tensor. It keeps giving me `InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): unique expects a 1D vector.`
Example:

```
def knnVote():
  '''
  KNN using majority vote
  '''
  #nearest indices
  A = tf.constant([1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8])
  print(A.shape)

  nearest_k_y, idx, votes = tf.unique_with_counts(A)
  print("y", nearest_k_y.eval())
  print("idx", idx.eval())
  print("votes", votes.eval())
  majority = tf.argmax(votes)
  predict_res = tf.gather(nearest_k_y, majority)


  print("majority", majority.eval())
  print("predict", predict_res.eval())
  return predict_res
```

Result:

```
y [1 2 4 7 8]
idx [0 0 1 2 2 2 3 4 4]
votes [2 1 3 1 2]
majority 2
predict 4
```

But how can I extend this to N by D input A, such as the case when `A = tf.constant([[1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8],
[2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]])`

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`tf.while_loop`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/while_loop) to iterate over `A` rows and process each row independently. This requires a little bit of dark magic with `shape_invariants` (to accumulate the results) and careful processing in a loop body. But it becomes more or less clear after you stare at it for some time.

Here's a code:

```
def multidimensionalKnnVote():
  A = tf.constant([
    [1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8],
    [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6],
  ])

  def cond(i, all_idxs, all_vals):
    return i < A.shape[0]

  def body(i, all_idxs, all_vals):
    nearest_k_y, idx, votes = tf.unique_with_counts(A[i])
    majority_idx = tf.argmax(votes)
    majority_val = nearest_k_y[majority_idx]

    majority_idx = tf.reshape(majority_idx, shape=(1,))
    majority_val = tf.reshape(majority_val, shape=(1,))

    new_idxs = tf.cond(tf.equal(i, 0),
                       lambda: majority_idx,
                       lambda: tf.concat([all_idxs, majority_idx], axis=0))

    new_vals = tf.cond(tf.equal(i, 0),
                       lambda: majority_val,
                       lambda: tf.concat([all_vals, majority_val], axis=0))

    return i + 1, new_idxs, new_vals

  # This means: starting from 0, apply the `body`, while the `cond` is true.
  # Note that `shape_invariants` allow the 2nd and 3rd tensors to grow.
  i0 = tf.constant(0)
  idx0 = tf.constant(0, shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int64)
  val0 = tf.constant(0, shape=(1,), dtype=tf.int32)
  _, idxs, vals = tf.while_loop(cond, body,
                                loop_vars=(i0, idx0, val0),
                                shape_invariants=(i0.shape, tf.TensorShape([None]), tf.TensorShape([None])))

  print('majority:', idxs.eval())
  print('predict:', vals.eval())
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use [tf.map_fn](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/map_fn) to apply a function to each row of a matrix variable

```
def knnVote(A):
  nearest_k_y, idx, votes = tf.unique_with_counts(A)
  majority = tf.argmax(votes)
  predict_res = tf.gather(nearest_k_y, majority)
  return predict_res

sess = tf.Session()
with sess.as_default():
  B = tf.constant([[1, 1, 2, 4, 4, 4, 7, 8, 8],
                   [2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 4, 4, 5, 6]])
  C = tf.map_fn(knnVote, B)
  print(C.eval())
```